# How to use JVM parameters for web application running on tomcat, on linux machine

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, concurrent-mark-sweep

I want to use a different garbage collector than the default Parallel GC for my web application when deployed on my production server, which will be on linux.

Say for an example i want to use Concurrent Mark Sweep GC for the application.

Now i have read that we can use this by adding `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` and various other JVM parameters to fine tune it.

So while packaging my war using maven i include this extra JVM parameters.
example:

```
mvn clean package -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

The war is packaged, i deploy it on my tomcat server which is running on linux environment.

**Note i package this war on a windows machine then deploy the war in linux machine using putty and winscp**

What i don't understand is how will this ensure that CMS GC is running? I mean shouldn't i include these changes where my application is running?

Or including these JVM parameters while packaging the was is good enough.

Same goes if i want to include various other JVM parameters, including while packaging the war is good to go or we need to include these some where else too?

Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these parameters in `[TOMCAT_HOME]/bin/catalina.sh` with `JAVA_OPTS`

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

It doesn't have any effect on providing these while packaging the war file.

Comment: Giving this as JAVA_OPTS, but then tomcat not restarting or stopping or simply starting
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark"

Comment: @RahulLao That should go as seperate question. I pointed out the place to add those JVM flags.